# How to get DISTINCT rows on a relation in Yii2 Active record

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-active-records

I have a AieDetail model as below:

```
  class AieDetail extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
  {
      public function getDepts()
      {
          return $this->hasOne(Department::className(), ['DEPT_CODE' => 'DEPT_CODE']);
      }
  }
```

I have this query that I want to use to select distinct COL_ABBREV column on Department table

```
  $aie_detail = AieDetail::find()->alias('AD')
                        ->select(['DEPT.COL_ABBREV'])
                        ->joinWith(['depts DEPT'])
                        ->where(['not',['DEPT.COL_ABBREV' => ['CA']]])
                        ->distinct()
                        ->all();
    return $aie_detail;
```

The value of **$aie_detail** is a query instead of an array of data. What is the correct approach to get the rows?

Comment: What do you mean that `$aie_detail` is query? The `all()` method of `\yii\db\ActiveQuery` cannot return query. It will always be an array. It might be an empty array, an array of models or an array of data, depending on whether you use `asArray()` in query. If it's a query then you probably didn't call the `all()` method or you've overriden `AieDetail::find()` to return something else than `\yii\db\ActiveQuery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $aie_detail = AieDetail::find()
                        ->select([Department::tableName() . '.COL_ABBREV'])
                        ->joinWith('depts')
                        ->where([
                          '!=',
                          Department::tableName() . '.COL_ABBREV',
                         'CA'
                        ])
                        ->distinct()
                        ->asArray()
                        ->all();
```

if you got any undefined index error include foreign keys used in the relation to the select statement or use leftJoin() method instead of joinWith().

if you want to select more data and distinct based on single column, then add groupBy() with arguments having distinct columns

Answer (score -1):

```
$aie_detail = AieDetail::find()->alias('AD')
    ->select('Department.COL_ABBREV')
    ->joinWith(['depts'])
    ->where(['not','Department.COL_ABBREV', 'CA'])
    ->distinct()
    ->all();
```

You have to pass in actual table name when using '.' operator in selecting a column in query.

Comment: That's not true. He is using alias correctly. See examples for `joinWith` in documentation https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail